# Kendo JS Dependency not working for Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Actually i used to bind my data-source using kendo Grid.

I checked kendo.all.min.js is working fine but i dont want unwanted js files while loading so include the Grid dependency files in my code but it does not works...

It shows an error in console. This is my js

```
 <script src="@Href("~/Scripts/libs/kendo.grid.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="@Href("~/Scripts/libs/kendo.core.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="@Href("~/Scripts/libs/kendo.data.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The files are not included in the right order. For example kendo.core.js should be first. Here is the documentation which lists the proper order of dependencies: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies#grid

Comment: I follow this procedure boss it's working fine  http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/kendo-grid-what-script-files-do-i-include.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.710/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.710/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.710/kendo.data.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/kendo/2012.2.710/kendo.grid.min.js"></script>

Put like this it's working...
```